Fail_install_gem_ruby_windows10(x64) - jekyll
I hope you are well, I have a problem wanting to lift my service in Jekyll.
It happens that I am working jekyll with GitHub pages and the site has already been generated with its files in the local cloned directory of the GitHub repository. However when executing the command:

bundle exec jekyll serve

I've output:
"Could not find gem 'wdm (~> 0.1.1)' in cached gems or installed locally.
Run bundle install to install missing gems."
Note: I already installed ruby 3.3.0 and the jekyll version is 4.3.3 on windows 10
Please, could you tell me what could be happening, this is the first time I've tried to work with Jekyll.
I tried running 2 commands:
> gem install wdm -v 0.1.1
> bundle install

But none of them gave a solution.
I was hoping it would install the missing gem and the service would run but it didn´t

What happens when you run bundle install? Any error messages or is wdm visible anywhere in the output?

Hi, Casper! Thans for comment. The output is: C:\Windows\system32>gem install wdm
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing wdm:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Remember to upvote and mark as solved in case the answer worked for you.

Your issue is that the wdm gem fails to build for some reason. However wdm is not mandatory for Jekyll to work on Windows.
Therefore you can just comment out the wdm gem from your Gemfile, and Jekyll will fall back to another method of file polling, and everything should work:
# Performance-booster for watching directories on Windows
# gem "wdm", "~> 0.1.1", :platforms => [:mingw, :x64_mingw, :mswin]

Note that this is only one solution. There may be another solution which would involve figuring out why wdm fails build, but it will be more complicated to solve. By just commenting out wdm it will allow you to get up and running the quickest.
